# Validate specific items in list within model

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am using fluent validation to validate the model

I have a Categories list within the model

// this works

```
 RuleForEach(x => x.Categories)
     .Must((x, cat) => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
     .WithMessage("{0}", (x, cat) => cat.ValidationMessage);
```

But I only want to check specific categories, so I am doing something like this. However it errors saying

> Property name could not be automatically determined for expression x
> => x.Categories.FirstOrDefault(y => (y.CategoryId == 123)). Please specify either a custom property name by calling 'WithName'.'

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Categories.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CategoryId == 123))
    .Must((x, cat) => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
    .WithMessage("{0}", (x, cat) => cat.ValidationMessage);
```

A Category looks something like this:

```
 public class Category
 {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
        public string ValidationMessage { get; set; }
 }
```

my Model has a `List<Category> Categories`;

Comment: I'm not familiar with fluentvalidation but why not just make an inverse of the filter part of the validation like `Must((x, cat) => cat.CategoryId != 123 || cat.SelectedOption != 0)`? As for the exception it asks for an expression that returns a property so it can then use the expression to extract the name of the property. However you're not passing it a property but the result of computation applied to a property (with no backing property on the object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `When` and `Unless` [operators](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html) to include or exclude items from the validation:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Categories)
    .Must((x, cat) => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
    .When(x => x.Categories.Any(y => y.CategoryId == 123))
    .WithMessage("{0}", (x, cat) => cat.ValidationMessage);
```

---

EDIT: Based on the newly revealed requirement.

> SelectedOption value check must be done against only on that Category where the Id is 123

My suggestion is to create a separate validator for that.

```
public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
{
      public CategoryValidator()
      {
         RuleFor(category => category)
          .Must(cat => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
          .When(cat => cat.CategoryId == 123);
      }
}
```

And register this validator for each category.

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Categories)
   .SetValidator(new CategoryValidator());
```

---

EDIT 2: Support multiple categories

```
public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
{
      public static readonly ImmutableArray<int> specialCategories 
          = ImmutableArray.Create(123, 456, 789);
    
      public CategoryValidator()
      {
         RuleFor(category => category)
          .Must(cat => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
          .When(cat => specialCategories.Contains(cat.CategoryId))
          .WithMessage(cat => cat.ErrorMessage);
      }
}
```

Comment: Categories is a list, so this doesn't compile

Comment: @rakos Could you please share with in this case your simplified domain model?

Comment: @rakos As I understand your question and your model you want to enforce a certain rule if one of the related category's Id is 123. Do I understand correctly? I've updated my suggestion based on this assumption.

Comment: I want to check that SeletedOption != 0 for one of my categories that has a CategoryId  123. Each Category in the list has a unique CategoryId

Comment: @raklos I've edited my suggestion based on your comment.

Comment: unfortunately no, I needed to *check specific categories*, so would need to use different values for the categoryId, also the validation message is bound to the Category object so would need to return that.... anyway i have put an answer as to what is working but i am not happy with it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `FirstOrDefault`, so it will try to validate only the first Category with `CategoryId == 123`.
Instead you should use `.Where` so you will filter all categories with that id for validation:

```
RuleForEach(x => x.Categories)
.Where(cat => cat.CategoryId == 123)
.Must((x, cat) => cat.SelectedOption != 0)
.WithMessage("{0}", (x, cat) => cat.ValidationMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not happy with the solution, but this seems to work

```
 var categoriesToCheck = new int[] { 123, 456, 789 };
 foreach (var categoryId in categoriesToCheck)
 {
    RuleFor(x => x.Categories)
      .Must((x, cat) => x.Categories.Any(y => y.CategoryId == categoryId && y.SelectedOption != 0))
      .WithMessage("{0}", (x, cat) => x.Categories.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CategoryId == categoryId).ValidationMessage);

  }
```